# How to work with group by and joins using sql or eloquent?

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

I have 5 table joined together. Now, I want to have sql or eloquent query where I will get result in group by.

Query I tried -

```
SELECT f.name AS formName, u.fname, u.lname, p.id AS pageId, 
       p.name, s.heading, count(r.response) AS response 
FROM `form_response` AS r 
LEFT JOIN `forms` AS f ON f.id = r.formId 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = r.adminId 
LEFT JOIN `page_section` AS s ON s.id = r.sectionId 
LEFT JOIN `page` As p ON p.id = r.pageId 
WHERE r.adminId = '.Auth::user()->id.' 
GROUP BY s.id
```

Here, `forms, users, page` tables has many to one relation with `form_response` table. And `page_section` has one to one relation with `form_response`. Now, I want a count of responses group by section.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please show your expected output in tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include everything in your `SELECT` statement in your `GROUP BY` when doing the aggregate function `count(r.response`).

I think you can get what you want using a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.name AS formName, u.fname, u.lname, p.id AS pageId, 
       p.name, s.heading, s.id, count(r.response) OVER (ORDER BY r.sectionId) AS response 
FROM `form_response` AS r 
LEFT JOIN `forms` AS f ON f.id = r.formId 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = r.adminId 
LEFT JOIN `page_section` AS s ON s.id = r.sectionId 
LEFT JOIN `page` As p ON p.id = r.pageId 
WHERE r.adminId = '.Auth::user()->id.'
```